# What is the best Adobe program to make an animated logo?

Tags: logo, software-recommendation, animation

I already have the idea in my head but I'm not sure how to execute.

I have a couple of years experience with Illustrator and have designed several "stop action" artboards but I know there has to be a better way.

The logo is made up of several pieces of the same shape. I took all of the pieces apart and made it look like a puzzle to be put back together. The shapes move around, like the puzzle is being solved and when it is complete, it forms a hexagon. The hexagon will inflate like a bubble, then deflate slightly to the final logo, which is a hexagon with all sides slightly concave.

I have access to all Adobe programs now but I don't want to waste time learning several that won't help me achieve the end goal for this project.

Comment: Ideas arent worth anything, only implementations that turn amazing are. (Ideas are always perfect in your mind, they just arent so perfect once you start to implement things. No because of lack of tools but actual idea in your brain is a half truth)

Comment: Where is it going to be used? There are many javascript solutions for making svg animations super easy but that's not going to help you much if you need it for a video.

Comment: Mostly on the website and maybe used on the app. It will be a quick one.

Comment: If you decide to go with AE, I'd suggest trying [Bodymovin](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web) plugin. Here's one tutorial that seems to outline what it does pretty well: https://youtu.be/h8tInajwIHo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to learn to animate, then After Effects is the way to go. While you can more or less let things move around in most Adobe tools, I'd say that After Effects is by far the best tool for this, with the best control over any aspect. You can create your assets in Illustrator and then animate them in After Effects.

Comment: This is what I started looking into but I wanted to make sure it was appropriate before I burned up all of the time on learning it when it wasn't what I needed. Between SkillShare and Lynda, I think I'll get it worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From Adobe's options, I agree After effects is the one, but the most suitable program could also be a 3D one depending on the "look".

You can also take a look at [Blender](https://www.blender.org/). But it can potentially be a challenge to learn if you are not familiar with any 3D program. The good thing is that there are a lot of [tutorials out there](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender%20logo).

Comment: I have stayed with 2D thus far but I am going to explore 3D soon. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that After Effects is by far the best software to do this. However, it can have a pretty steep learning curve to fully understand keyframing and getting things to animate smoothly.

Another option is to use the Photoshop 'Timeline' feature. It is pretty similar to stop motion animation and will be fairly tedious to manually move all of the puzzle pieces around.

Comment: That was my concern with Photoshop and I'm already a total newbie in Ps. Might as well give Ae a whirl. Thanks for the advice!